# Heroku PHP app getting 302 error on some links, not others

Tags: apache, http, heroku, php-7, http-status-code-302

I'm migrating a working PHP app from my localhost, XAMPP, to Heroku and a few of my links give me a 302 error and the load page says:

"This page isn’t working

mywebsite.heroku.com sent an invalid response.

ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT"

Here is my code for that particular link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $web_url . 'admin'; ?>">Admin</a>
```

Here's the code for another broken link that does the same thing:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $web_url . 'account'; ?>">Login/Register</a>
```

HOWEVER, here is the code for the link directly beneath that one that works perfectly:

```
<a href="<?php echo $web_url . 'cart'; ?>">View Cart</a>
```

Here's the code that has that variable defined.

```
$web_url = "https://" . $_ENV["HTTP_HOST"] . "/";
```

EDIT: I've narrowed it down to links that take users to pages where data is entered. It's an ecommerce website so account registration, login, admin login, and checkout where the user enters billing info and credit card.

I think it has to do with the apache server. I do -not- have an .htaccess file so there's nothing in there that would cause this redirect.

Any ideas are appreciated. I am trying to avoid spending a week reading the entire apache documentation.

Answer (score 0):

would suspect the problem to be here...

```
$app_path = '/' . $dirs[1] . '/' . $dirs[2] . '/';
```

which should rather be (due to zero-based indexes):

```
if(sizeof($dirs) == 2) {
    $app_path = '/' . $dirs[0] . '/' . $dirs[1] . '/';
}
```

better rewrite with `mod_rewrite`, before the request hits any script.

... and when developing on the localhost, [xdebug](https://xdebug.org) is a good tool.

Comment: I shouldn't have included that part of the code as it was not in use. I am git pushing all my changes to the server and making it run solely off there as I was getting different reactions to changes on the web server and local host. Before putting it on Heroku, it ran perfectly fine on my localhost.